# Get package path with rospy

Tags: ros, rospy, path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using ROS with rospy and I need to get the package path to load some data files, because I can't use relative paths while it's not always expected to run the nodes from any fixed location.

So, does anyone know how could I get the absolute path of a package?

Thank you in advance,

XNor

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63475/get-package-path-with-rospy/) by [XNor](https://answers.ros.org/users/4972/xnor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-05-25

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to do that is documented here: [ROS Filesystem Concepts/Packages](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Packages#Client_Library_Support)

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [XNor](https://answers.ros.org/users/4972/xnor/) on 2013-05-26**:
Thank you so much, I was searching about it but I didn't find anything. I knew there sould be a way.